# Breadth First Search of a list that represents a tree structure

Tags: algorithm, list, tree, breadth-first-search

I am trying to develop an algorithm that can read through a list of dictionary keys that contain some data.

Example of list that is read into application

```
ID: 1 Level: 0 Data:"Animal"
ID: 2 Level: 1 Data:"Dog"
ID: 3 Level: 1 Data:"Cat"
ID: 4 Level: 1 Data:"Sheep"
ID: 5 Level: 2 Data:"Collie"
ID: 6 Level: 2 Data:"Dalmation"
ID: 7 Level: 3 Data:"Tabby"
ID: 8 Level: 4 Data:"Suffolk"
ID: 9 Level: 5 Data:"Jimmy"
ID: 10 Level: 6 Data:"Sally"
```

Now if I wanted to do a search for "Sally" the program would read through the tree structure to return:

> Sally is a dog of type dalmation

This can be calculated through the following logic:

`Animal` is at the top of the tree and `Dog`, `Cat` and `Sheep` form the next level. **Level 2 is then assigned to the first element of Level 1, Level 3 to the second element of Level 1 and Level 4 is assigned to the third element of Level** 1. As Level 1 has been filled out I move to the next Level; in this case Level 2. Level 2 has 2 elements so Level 5 is applied to the first element and Level 6 is applied to the second element, *in this case `Sally` being a child of `Dalmation` which is a child of `Dog`*.

I imagine that a breadth first search algorithm would work best as the lower ID is always located on the left of a level on the tree. I need to be able to search the tree to find the value input (in this case `Sally`) and then find the other values in the tree that are a direct link to the top of the tree (`Animal`).

Comment: ho did you find out that sally is a child of dalmation? is anything sally must be child of jimmy because sally is lvl 6 and only jimmy is lvl 5! Are you missing something here or I dont understand your question?

Comment: Perhaps I haven't really explained it very well! "Animal" is at the top of the tree and "Dog", "Cat" and "Sheep" form the next level. Level 2 is then assigned to the first element of Level 1, Level 3 to the second element of Level 1 and Level 4 is assigned to the third element of :Level 1. As Level 1 has been filled out I move to the next Level; in this case Level 2. Level 2 has 2 elements so Level 5 is applied to the first element and Level 6 is applied to the second element, in this case "Sally" being a child of "Dalmation" which is a child of "Dog".

Comment: Ok, edit your question and add this description to it.

So what is the problem with BFS or DFS?

Comment: Thank you. Well I'm not sure on how to implement this in an efficient way. I was hoping someone could help with some advice.

Comment: Make it clear what is there that you dont understand, as long as I can see you dont even have a language related problem because there isnt any language tag in your question, so what is your problem with bfs or dfs?

Comment: At the moment I haven't written any code, I am trying to design a solution to the problem first

Comment: @CMac could you consider accepting the answer if it answered your question or were you looking for a different explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing bfs/dfs to answer one query say find "Sally" would suffice. You will need  a hashtable **H** such that when traversing the tree and you are at a node say **x** then just store in hash table the parent of **x**, **H[x]=parent(x)**. Also note you can mark parent of root node as root itself or some value such as -1,lets go with -1.You can use bfs/dfs to find the node filling the hash table as you traverse. Now if you get a query "Sally", do the following after you have found "Sally" after using bfs/dfs(not included in pseudocode):(its a pseudocode not in a specific language )

```
           search_element = sally // element to be searched
           list=[] // empty list
           while H[search_element]! = -1
                list.append(H[search_element])
                search_element = H[search_element]
```

Your list would look like **[animal,dog,dalmation]** so you can traverse from beginning saying sally is an animal,its a dog, its a dalmation.(or whatever order you want because your tree order was bit confusing).